# Is it possible in Excel to combine AND and OR in string searches?

Tags: excel, filter, boolean-logic

I have a fairly large dataset (multi tens of thousands lines) which contains a column of freetext data  cells.  I would like to filter the dataset so that only lines with specific words featuring in the freetext cells are returned, however I would like to use both AND and OR for my parameters.  Is this doable?

So I would like to filter, for example, for
green AND hair OR
blue AND hair OR
purple AND hair

I know how to do this with just OR in the string (green OR blue OR purple OR hair), but that would return lines with just green or blue or purple and without the reference to hair also being in the same cell.  I could use " " e.g. "green hair" but it's possible that the references to green and hair may not be in that exact phrase so that would remove relevant lines, for example it wouldn't keep a cell with the line "the girl's hair was green" in the freetext cell.  Hope this makes sense! I suspect it may be that Excel just doesn't do this, but hoping to be proved wrong!

I am a bit stumped with this one so haven't tried too much yet.  I had wondered about trying an advanced filter but don't think this will work as I'm trying to do an AND for some of those criteria

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and you can use `ISNUMBER` and `FIND`/`SEARCH` to search within text.

Comment: To filter your dataset, add a helper column at the end of your data, and use the formulas suggested above to determine whether to include or exclude the row. Then you can apply the filter on the helper column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The following example shows how to use Advanced Filter to get the required filtered data.

| Line | ColumnA |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | =AND(OR(ISERR(SEARCH("green",A12))<>TRUE,ISERR(SEARCH("yellow",A12))<>TRUE,ISERR(SEARCH("blue",A12))<>TRUE),ISERR(SEARCH("hair",A12))<>TRUE) |  |
| ... |  |  |
| 14 | Items |  |
| 15 | Green hair |  |
| 16 | Her hair was yellow |  |
| 17 | Yellow |  |
| 18 | Red |  |
| 19 | blue hair |  |
| 20 | Blue bus |  |
| 21 | yellow bus |  |
| 22 | red bus |  |
| 23 | Long hair |  |
| 24 | short hair |  |
| ... |  |  |

In Advanced Filter  Select **Filter in place** and set **List range**:= $A$14:$A$24 and **Filter range**:= $A$1:$A$2

The result

| Line | ColumnA |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | Items |  |
| 15 | Green hair |  |
| 16 | Her hair was yellow |  |
| 19 | blue hair |  |